# Is there something wrong with my If Statements?

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean, logic, boolean-logic

This function checks if the values in the text boxes are parsable or not. This method is called upon in the method below this.

```
    private bool CheckForInvalidEntries()
    {
        bool ParseIsSuccessfull; int result; //These 2 variables are for trying to parse the entries in the Stat text boxes
        bool ContainsInvalidEntry = false;

        if ((ParseIsSuccessfull = int.TryParse(P1STRtextbox.Text, out result)) == false)
        {
            ContainsInvalidEntry = true;
        }
        else if ((ParseIsSuccessfull = int.TryParse(P1DEXtextbox.Text, out result)) == false)
        {
            ContainsInvalidEntry = true;
        }
        else if ((ParseIsSuccessfull = int.TryParse(P1VIGtextbox.Text, out result)) == false)
        {
            ContainsInvalidEntry = true;
        }
        else if ((ParseIsSuccessfull = int.TryParse(P1RMtextbox.Text, out result)) == false)
        {
            ContainsInvalidEntry = true;
        }
        else if ((ParseIsSuccessfull = int.TryParse(P1BMtextbox.Text, out result)) == false)
        {
            ContainsInvalidEntry = true;
        }
        else ContainsInvalidEntry = false;


        return ContainsInvalidEntry;
    }
```

This function is the event where if the process stat points button is clicked

```
    private void p1ProcessPointsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool EntriesAreInvalid = new bool();

        EntriesAreInvalid = CheckForInvalidEntries();

        if (EntriesAreInvalid == true)
        {
            P1STRtextbox_TextChanged(sender, e);
            P1DEXtextbox_TextChanged(sender, e);
            P1VIGtextbox_TextChanged(sender, e);
            P1RMtextbox_TextChanged(sender, e);
            P1BMtextbox_TextChanged(sender, e);

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
```

[image: The frame Im having problems with]

**FUNCTIONALITY:** When the user presses the "Process Stat Points" button, the program checks whether the entries in the 5 text boxes are able to be parsed(in the CheckForInvalidEntries method). It then returns a bool value to the EntriesAreInvalid variable(in the p1ProcessPointsBtn_Click method). If the entries are not parsable, do action A, if the entries are parsable, do action B.

**PROBLEM:** If the numbers are parsable in all the text boxes, I don't get a result. Im only getting results if the text boxes are not parsable. I think it has something to do with the if statements within the "CheckForInvalidEntries" method. What can I do to fix my problem. Your time and effort is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remove the `= new bool()` part of the code. It smells funky to me.

Comment: This whole method smells funky

Comment: Haahah I know the problem is in the CheckForInvalidEntries Method its so damn funky. I just think the logical approach I took was not good. Even logical advice would be nice :)

Comment: I see no problems with that method. Can you debug the code and find the point in code where the state of the application is different from what you would expect?

Comment: if i had to guess, you have to logic backwards. your method is going to stop on the first *valid* entry and return true; it sounds like you want it to stop on the first *invalid* entry and return false?

Comment: I want it to stop on the first invalid entry and return true. Hence the reason ContainsInvalidEntry is set to true in the if statements.

Answer (score 1):

TryParse sets Result to zero if the conversion fails. Since you keep calling TryParse you keep resetting Result.

If you only want to check for parsing errors, this ought to work:

```
ContainsInvalidEntry = false;
ContainsInvalidEntry |= !int.TryParse(P1STRtextbox.Text, out result));
ContainsInvalidEntry |= !int.TryParse(P1DEXtextbox.Text, out result));
ContainsInvalidEntry |= !int.TryParse(P1VIGtextbox.Text, out result));
ContainsInvalidEntry |= !int.TryParse(P1RMtextbox.Text, out result));
ContainsInvalidEntry |= !int.TryParse(P1BMtextbox.Text, out result));
return ContainsInvalidEntry;
```

Aside: Comparing boolean values to true and false is a bit (Pardon the pun.) strange. `if ( ( ParsedOkay == ( false ) ) )` may be valid, but `if ( !ParsedOkay )` is more common.

Comment: Should I try setting result back to 1 in each if statement that deals with failing?

Comment: I've never saw a structure of code like this. May you briefly explain what you are doing here. I mean I get the gist of it. Seems like a more neat and efficient way of doing the same thing I was trying to do.

Comment: @user3134679 - The code assumes that there is no invalid entry. Then, for each field to be parsed, it performs a logical OR of the negated TryParse (!) with the current status. Thus, any failing TryParse will set ContainsInvalidEntry to true. Alternatively you could simply `return !( int.TryParse( Thing1, out DontCare ) && int.TryParse( Thing2, out DontCare ) && ... );`. If any of the TryParse calls fails then it will return true due to the logical NOT (!).

Answer (score 1):

i was too confused by your code. But i think this will help you. If i got you right you wanted to check if all the text in the textboxes is parsable to an int. And if it is so you wanted to print out "succes";

```
private bool isParsable(TextBox t) //takes a TextBox as paramater and returns true if
    {                              // its parsable
        int i = 4;
        if (int.TryParse(t.Text, out i) == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;            
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(isParsable(tbox1) == true && isParsable(tbox2) == true) //if every textbox
        {                                                          //is parsable print
            tblock1.Text = "succes";
        }
        else
        {
            tblock1.Text = "error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You got it. Thanks exactly what I want my program to do. Im going to try it out right now

Comment: What is the significance of int i = 4; How come you gave it that value?

Comment: 'code'if (isParsable(P1STRtextbox) == true && isParsable(P1STRtextbox) == true && isParsable(P1VIGtextbox) == true && isParsable(P1RMtextbox) == true && isParsable(P1BMtextbox) == true)'code' I have a total of 5 textboxes to parse. Was wondering if the int i = 4 ould affect that.

Comment: The "int i = 4" is because you need an integer as out to call the function.

Comment: I'm the last one to try to save a keystroke by using some bizarre trick, but I'm not paid for code by the pound. Writing `{ if ( something == (true) ) { return ( true ); ) else { { { return ( ( ( false ) ) );;; } } } }` instead of `return something;` is rather clumsy. The bright side is that it lets you set a breakpoint on one return or the other. The downside is it makes it look like you don't trust truth. You might also want to get used to the condition operator (?:), e.g. `foo.Text = Valid( bar ) ? "success" : "failure";`.

Comment: you could make it shorter: in isParsable method just do : `return int.TryParse(t.Text, out i);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to write your if statements like this, it's too messy and unnecessary. Complex code always prone to error,

Instead of this:

```
 if ((ParseIsSuccessfull = int.TryParse(P1STRtextbox.Text, out result)) == false)
```

You could write:

```
if(!int.TryParse(P1STRtextbox.Text, out result))
```

Because TryParse already returning a bool result.If you want check whether it's false just put negation operator (!) beginning of your statement. Also you can write a simple method to check  whether your texts are parsable or not:

```
static bool CheckForParse(params string[] values) 
{
   int x;
   if(values.Lenght > 0)
   {
       for(int i=0; i<values.Lenght;i++)
       {
          if(!int.TryParse(values[i], x)) return false;
       }
       return true;

    } else { return false }

    return false;
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
bool result = CheckForParse(P1STRtextbox.Text,
                            P1DEXtextbox.Text,
                            P1VIGtextbox.Text,
                            P1RMtextbox.Text,
                            P1BMtextbox.Text);
if(result)
{
   P1STRtextbox_TextChanged(sender, e);
   P1DEXtextbox_TextChanged(sender, e);
   ...
}
```